# Query for Photos from Parse into UIImage array - Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uiimage, swift2

I am getting 'array out of range' error with the below.  The code doesn't seem to be executing the inner block. It says my array has nothing in it, yet my print(objects.count) = 7.  My Parse table name is "Photos" and it has 7 PFFiles in a column called "imageFile" - there must something wrong with my getDataInBackgroundWithBlock?   I am using swift2 and xcode 7 Thanks!

```
  var pageImages: [UIImage] = []

    func xyz() {

    let query = PFQuery(className:"Photos")

    query.whereKey("userId", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId)!)

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            for object in objects! {

                let userPicture = object["imageFile"] as! PFFile

                userPicture.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if (error == nil) {
                            let image = UIImage(data:imageData!)
                            self.pageImages.append(image!)

                            print("pageImages.count \(self.pageImages.count)")

                        }
                    }
            }
            print("objects.count \(objects!.count)")
            print("pageImagesOutside.count \(self.pageImages.count)")    

        }
        self.loadPage()
    }) }

  self.imageView1.image = pageImages[1]
    self.imageView2.image = pageImages[2]
    self.imageView3.image = pageImages[3]
    self.imageView4.image = pageImages[4]
    self.imageView5.image = pageImages[5]
    self.imageView6.image = pageImages[6]
    self.imageView7.image = pageImages[7]
```

Answer (score 0):

The first item , or first index of an array is 0, not 1!

So your array indexes should be 0-6, not 1-7!

So:

```
self.imageView1.image = pageImages[0]
self.imageView2.image = pageImages[1]
self.imageView3.image = pageImages[2]
```

Have a good day:)

Comment: cvinette,  I wish it were that simple.  Unfortunately the array isn't even filling up with UIImages.  When i step through code it goes to getDataInBackgroundWithBlock and jumps through to the end of the block, nothing inside the block gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the syntax for the Swift 2 changes. [The iOS guide has been updated](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries-basic-queries)

Update the query

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
    (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    ...
}
```

to the following

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    ...
}
```

As cnvinette has mentioned, you should steer clear of directly referencing array indices and that is what's directly causing the issue. Due to the syntax change, the array is not being populated correctly, leading to an array out of bounds error later on. Definitely look into refactoring that so your code is not a brittle.

Comment: When I change the argument to PFObject, I get the following error:  Cannot convert value of type '([PFObject]?, NSError?) -> Void' to expected argument type 'PFArrayResultBlock?'

Comment: Double check that the parenthesis and curly braces are properly updated as well. If it's still throwing an error, you should go ahead and file a bug report with Parse. That's exactly how they show to do it in their swift 2 documentation, so if it's wrong they need to know about it.

Comment: Thanks Russell, I'm suspicious that maybe iOS9 ATS security is preventing the imageData retrieval, although turning ATS off didn't seem to help.  I will take this issue to Parse.

Comment: I'm getting the following ATS error:  "App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file."